# Return a value from a keyword in [setup]

Tags: robotframework

In a keyword run in the setup of a test case I have a timestamp which I have to use later in the test case body. What is the best way to return it to the test case body? I have only thought out to use a test-scope variable but ideally would like to pass it as a return parameter.

To illustrate:

```
*** Keywords ***
setup keyword
    ${ts} =    evaluate    <whatever>

*** Test Cases ***
case1
    [setup]    setup keyword
    #here I need ${ts}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return values in a setup. Your two choices are to set a test level variable in your setup keyword (using the [Set test variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable) keyword), or call your setup keyword as the first step in your test rather than as a setup step. Personally I prefer the former.

Comment: I agree that using a test level variable gives a cleaner solution. Perhaps it's not so ugly as I initially thought. Thank you, I tick your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a suite variable, since the setup is common to the entire suite.

```
*** keywords ***
setup keyword
    ${temp} =    evaluate    
    Set Suite Variable  ${ts}  ${temp}


*** Test Cases ***
case1
    [setup]    setup keyword
    #here I need ${ts}
```

Comment: No, in my situation different test cases have their own setups so using a suite variable results in an unnecessary wide scope.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem while trying to convert pytest setup and teardown into robotframework. Following is my setup and teardown in pytest:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def configuration_setup(request):
    shutil.copy(config, backup)
    modify(config)

    def teardown():
        shutil.copy(backup, config)    

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
```

I needed to return the teardown function during the execution of the setup.

```
def configuration_setup():
    shutil.copy(config, backup)
    modify(config)

    def teardown():
        shutil.copy(backup, config)    
    return teardown
```

So I ended up using the `Set Test Variable` like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
Create config backup
    ${created_backup}    Configuration setup    config    backup
    Set Test Variable    ${undo_backup}    ${created_backup}
```

And then I can use the return value as my teardown.

```
*** Test Cases ***
A test case
    [Setup]    Create config backup
    Another Keywords    Arg1    Arg2
    [Teardown]    ${undo_backup()}
```